# How to solve differential equation - $x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+f(x)=0\ , f(x_0)=x_0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+f(x)=0\ , ~~~~~~f(x_0)=x_0$$
 I didn't even know what method to be used to solve this problem. How to find solution for this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Make the ansatz $$y=x^{\lambda}$$

Comment: This is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Euler_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given differential equation is $$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)+f(x)=0\tag1$$

Take $~x=e^z~$ i.e., $~z=\log x~$

Then $$f'=\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dz}\cdot \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{df}{dz}$$
$$\implies x~f'(x)=\frac{df}{dz}=Df\qquad \text{where}\quad D\equiv \frac{d}{dz}$$

Similarly, $$x^2~f''(x)=D(D-1)f$$
Then $~(1)~$ becomes, $$\{D(D-1)+D+1\}f=0\implies (D^2+1)f(x)=0$$

The general solution is $$f(x)=A~\cos z~+~B~\sin z=A~\cos(\log x)~+~B~\sin(\log x)$$
where $~A,~B~$ are constants which can be determined by the given condition $~f(x_0)=x_0~$ i.e., $~x_0=A~\cos(\log x_0)~+~B~\sin(\log x_0)~$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome